# Issues creating multiple jquery-ui sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have about 20 sliders on my page. I initially used  on my page but they are not responding nicely on iPad. I am now trying to use the jQuery-UI sliders (with jQuery ui touch punch) but cannot seem to initialize the sliders with the min/max values programatically.

### Slider HTML

`<div id="clientPackingOutRep" data-min="5000" data-max="50000" data-step="5000" class="slider"></div>`

### Slider JS

```
$(".slider").slider();

$(".slider").each(function(){
  $(this).slider("option", "min", $(this).attr("data-min")); 
  $(this).slider("option", "max", $(this).attr("data-max")); 
  $(this).slider("option", "step", $(this).attr("data-step"));       
});
```

The sliders get generated but when I try to use any of them this gets spit back to me in console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object 1500006000010000 has no method 'toFixed'`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those options accept numbers, not strings :

```
$(".slider").slider();

$(".slider").each(function(){
  $(this).slider("option", "min", parseInt($(this).data('min'),10)); 
  $(this).slider("option", "max", parseInt($(this).data('max'),10)); 
  $(this).slider("option", "step", parseInt($(this).data('step'),10));       
});
```